# How do I bring my map back to normal in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I used the command that unlocks everything in the map, but I regret it and want to set it back to normal. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Did you use the `tmm 1` console command? If yes, please edit this info into your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't go back to the state before executing the command except for reloading an old save.
Another alternative is to wipe all map markers if you don't mind exploring them again.

`TMM 1,0,1` - will show all markers without fast travel
`TMM 0` - will disable all markers

Comment: I see and the command to wipe it is TMM 1?

Comment: No, the command to wipe all markers (remove or disable) them is TMM 0